# youtube embed code with PHP

Tags: php

I have created a blog in php. Users can write something and post it. If this includes a web address then a link automated is created using this :

```
<?php

//...code

$row['comment'] = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><font color="#69aa35">$1</font></a>', $row['comment']);

?>
```

Using this in posts, text posted successfuly and web address displayed in a link format inside text. Any idea how can I change this, so that if there is a link of youtube, then a youtube frame to be created. For example in facebook, when you post a youtube address, a youtube frame created and posted instead of a link.

Comment: That code is irrelevant. You need regex for extracting youtube video slugs and then use that to create an iframe on the page.

Comment: 1. you are generating invalid html by using `<font>` tag; 2. use markdown [which you are already doing here on SO]; 3. you can them issue a replacement via `DOMDocument`on the generated output, for instance.

Comment: I just want a help of how I will change my preg_replace syntax(). I have notice that youtube uses a standar of "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" before of each video

Answer (score 2):

I have improved my answer and tested this code:

```
<?php
// This is your comment string containing the youtube link
$string="Here is a link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJHFXenOPi4";
// This will remove all links from the input string
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z;.\/?:@=_#&%~,+$]+/', $string, $matches);
foreach($matches as $url){
    // Parse each url within the comment data
    $input = parse_url($url);
    if ($input['host'] == 'youtube.com' || $input['host'] == 'www.youtube.com' ) {
        // If it is a youtube link, then parse the get variables
        parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $variables);
        // Echo out the iframe with the relevant video ID
        echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$variables['v'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this is what you were looking for, it has worked for me on a few tests

Answer (score 1):

You know the solution don't you? :) If the snippet contains youtube.com URL, then using the same pattern matching you can replace it with a youtube embed tag :)

Basically it will be something like this in pseudo-code.

- Check the comment pasted to see if youtube URL present (modify the same regex you are using for finding URL, just make it specific for youtube)
- If yes, then replace it with:

  `<iframe type="text/html" 
      width="640" 
      height="385" 
      src="<youtube URL>"
      frameborder="0">
  </iframe>`

Comment: any idea how I should change my preg_replace()?

Comment: try `^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$`

Comment: it gives me : Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '?'   Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: try escaping the ? - you should find enough resources in SO itself for regex that identifies youtube URL